# Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 in Android Studio new project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I know about this questions:

[Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0 android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45103230/2263683)

[Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47035406/2263683)

And I've read this documentations:

[Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

[Migrating to Android 8.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html#ptb)

*So I'm posting this question believing its not a duplicate.*

I've installed Android Studio 3.0.1. I didn't have any previous version before and I started a new project.

Every setting in Gradle file have been set by Android Studio itself and I've checked them all.

These are the file contents:

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.administrator.as301test"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }
```

**Top level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

I use `google()` in repositories as [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html#ptb) clearly says:

> ```
>   // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
>      // maven {
>      //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
>      // }
> ```

My gradle version is 4.1 so I don't need above code.

But I still get this error as the others have been asking about:

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Why should I get this error when I'm creating a new project in `AS 3.0.1` and it has been set all the necessary settings?

**Update**

@Rohit's answer somehow solved the issue but I still get same error for some other dependencies.

> Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1
>
> Could not resolve
>   com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1
>
> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12

Comment: test case change  your **`buildToolsVersion "26"`**

Comment: instead of `implementation` keyword try with `compile` too

Comment: @Prem same error with `buildToolsVersion "25"`

Comment: @AlexJolig change to **26**

Comment: @VivekMishra Tried as you suggested. failed with same error.

Comment: Uncheck `Offline work` option in File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle

Comment: @NazmulHaque It's already unchecked.

Comment: Try setting https proxy as mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47223907/1756069
Most probably, it will work for you.

Comment: @garnet Already did that.

Comment: So, it might have worked for you. Please confirm. I also got the same problem which you mentioned with AS 3.0.1. But, after specifying https proxy, it worked.

Comment: @garnet Google does not offer support in my country, and I'm always using https proxy. So no it didn't work. I fixed the problem and I will post my solution soon

Comment: @AlexJolig try removing  `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1`. It's giving no errors during the build.

Comment: Adding the following  solved my issue       `buildToolsVersion "26.0.2" `

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally I fixed the problem by modifying `build.gradle` like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

I've removed these lines as these will produce more errors:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

Also I had same problem with migrating an existing project from 2.3 to 3.0.1 and with modifying the project gradle files like this, I came up with a working solution:

**build.gradle** (module app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobaleghan.tablighcalendar"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.apps.dashclock:dashclock-api:2.0.0'
}
```

**Top level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that space in your `build.gradle` file in between `constraint` and `layout` intentional?

Comment: @RobRose Oops! That must been a mistake. Got fixed!

Comment: `BuildToolsVersion 26` is necessary?

Comment: @lololololol You must include `BuildToolsVersion`. the version depends on which one works for you

Comment: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container. I am getting this error.

Comment: @mangatinanda Are you sure you're using AS 3 and gradle version 3 ?

Comment: i build everyday in my ionic app ... after a month ... last night i cant build ... but i cant remember when i changed this configuration ... this is forth time that it changed by third party app or when i run ionic cordova build android or maybe when add new plugin... so i dont know when and how its changed and

Answer (score 10):

[image]goto Android->sdk->build-tools directory make sure you have all the versions required . if not , download them . after that 
goto File-->Settigs-->Build,Execution,Depoyment-->Gradle

choose ***use default gradle wapper (recommended)***

and untick ***Offline work***

gradle build finishes successfully for once you can change the settings

**If it dosent simply solve the problem**

check this link to find an appropriate support library revision

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions

Make sure that the compile sdk and target version same as the support library version.
It is recommended maintain network connection atleast for the first time build (Remember to rebuild your project after doing this)

Answer (score 8):

try this :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {

        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

}


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
```

It has worked for me

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess this somehow worked for some errors. Any suggestion for `Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1`?

Comment: This makes sense as 26.1.0 is not released yet as per https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html. It seems to be a bug in AS 3.0.1

Comment: @AlexJolig , com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0 or other versions

Answer (score 5):

I tried all of the above and nothing worked for me.

Then I followed Gradle Settings > Build Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Android Studio and checked "Disable embedded Maven repository".

Did a build with this checked and the problem was solved.

Comment: Wow, this did it for me too. Does anyone know why this is happening? It seems to take longer to build now... I was also using Kotlin in case that helps anyone else.

Answer (score 3):

Just go to
   File\Settings\Gradle. Deselect the "Offline work" box. Now you can connect and 
   download any necessary or missing dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Your android studio may be forgot to put :
   buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
you need 'buildTools' to develop related design and java file. And if there is no any buildTools are installed in Android->sdk->build-tools directory then download first.

Comment: Add buildToolsVersion "26.0.0" after compileSdkVersion in gradle(Module) file.

Comment: Adding `buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"` under `compileSdkVersion 26`, did not help. I still get the same error.

Comment: Then check your Android->sdk->build-tools directory which contains build tools versions you have installed.

Comment: I got `27.0.1`, `26.0.2` and `25.0.2` versions, installed

Comment: OK. Add compile in the place of implementation and testCompile in the place of testImplementation and use androidTestCompile in the place of androidTestImplementation.

Comment: why my android studio missing add buildToolsVersion?

Answer (score 2):

well got this answer from another site and don't want to take any credit for this but this solution works like butter.

Go to File\Settings\Gradle. Deselect the "Offline work" box. Now you can connect and download any necessary or missing dependencies.

Comment: What's the value-add over https://stackoverflow.com/a/48848256/101361 already posted here? Your answer part is a verbatim copy of it

Comment: ok well i didn't see that one and i got this from another site and thats why i said i got this answer from another site and not taking any credit for this. plus if someone came to this link and not that one then he will be seeing his solution right here. he doesn't have to search anymore or anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This work for me. In the **android\app\build.gradle** file you need to specify the following

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

and then find this

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7"
```

and make sure it says

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"
```

Comment: Excelente amigo muchas gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 2):

OK It's A Wrong Approach But If You Use it Like This :

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+"
```

Android Studio Will Use The Last Version It Has.

In My Case Was 26.0.0alpha-1.

**You Can See The Used Version In External Libraries (In The Project View).**

I Tried Everything But Couldn't Use Anything Above 26.0.0alpha-1, It Seems My IP Is Blocked By Google. Any Idea? Comment

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error occur when i tried to use gridView

I resolved it by removing this line from build.grade(Module) file

```
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to like the following.

[How to resolve repository certificate error in Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323909/how-to-resolve-repository-certificate-error-in-gradle-build/47545556#47545556)

Below steps may help:

**1. Add certificate to keystore-**

Import some certifications into Android Studio JDK cacerts from Android Studio’s cacerts.

Android Studio’s cacerts may be located in

```
{your-home-directory}/.AndroidStudio3.0/system/tasks/cacerts
```

I used the following import command.

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -v -srckeystore {src cacerts} -destkeystore {dest cacerts}
```

**2. Add modified cacert path to gradle.properties-**

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore={your-android-studio-directory}\\jre\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

Ref : https://www.cresco.co.jp/blog/entry/2014//

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache in android studio by 
File-> Invalidate cache -> invalidate
after invalidating 
build-> clean project 
Then you can able to build the project

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

change 26.0.0 to 26.0.1

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me. add configurations.all in app/build.gradle

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    }
}
```