# Mapbox Navigation v0.11.1 gradle error relating appcompat

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have created a blank project and it runs successfully till I add this line in the gradle build:     `implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1'`

Below is the build.gradle file for app level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aadhilahmed.navtest4"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.1@aar') {
        transitive=true
    }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And this is the project level build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the error message for the gradle build relates something to the v27.0.1 of appcompat, eventhough I use v26.1.0.Here it is.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/172.217.163.195] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.52.209] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.1
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/172.217.163.195] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.52.209] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-fragment:25.4.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.1
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-fragment:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-fragment/25.4.0/support-fragment-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-fragment/25.4.0/support-fragment-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-fragment:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-fragment/25.4.0/support-fragment-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-fragment/25.4.0/support-fragment-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/172.217.163.195] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-fragment:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-fragment/25.4.0/support-fragment-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-fragment/25.4.0/support-fragment-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.52.209] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-fragment:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-fragment/25.4.0/support-fragment-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-fragment/25.4.0/support-fragment-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/172.217.163.195] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.52.209] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.1 > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:2.2.10
      project :app > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1 > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.2.10
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/172.217.163.195] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.52.209] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1 > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.2.10
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-compat/25.4.0/support-compat-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-compat/25.4.0/support-compat-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-compat/25.4.0/support-compat-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-compat/25.4.0/support-compat-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/172.217.163.195] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-compat/25.4.0/support-compat-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-compat/25.4.0/support-compat-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.52.209] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-compat/25.4.0/support-compat-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-compat/25.4.0/support-compat-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1 > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.2.10 > com.mapzen.android:lost:3.0.4
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/172.217.163.195] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.52.209] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.4.0/support-annotations-25.4.0.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
  Required by:
      project :app > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1 > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.2.10 > com.mapzen.android:lost:3.0.4
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/172.217.163.195] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.52.209] failed: Connection refused: connect
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom'.
            > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.163.206] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

And If I remove this(`implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.11.1'`) line from gradle file, everything works properly again.I don't know from where this issue pops up. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check design dependency was missing

Comment: May I know what it is???

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

Comment: Sorry. still the same error.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47628187/5594218

Comment: Here you did mistake in mavenCentral() put in wrong gradle file[here some help for you that you can help to put gradle file dependancies](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview/)

Comment: No..it was not an answer relevant to my issue. I have a working project unlike the one in that question. The problem arises only after adding the navigation package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167698/discussion-between-minnukaanae-and-aadhil-ahmed).

Comment: I think mapbox is a wrapper on GoogleMaps & in your case maven() is reloading it. Check by removing maven() block with keeping mapbox implementation line in dependencies