# 'Could not resolve recyclerview-v7' Error, while updating gradle version and compile to implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am working on Android since 2 years. I never faced issue like this. 
After updating Android Studio and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3`, i am facing this issue.

**Issue:** **`Could not resolve RecyclerView-v7`**

This is a silly issue which make me stuck for 1 hour. This only happens in `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3`.

**Project level build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply from: rootProject.file('dependencies.gradle')

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App level build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.kpis.upkeep"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationId + "-v" + versionCode + "(" + versionName + ")")
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-T"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            versionNameSuffix "-R"
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility rootProject.ext.targetCompatibilityVersion
        sourceCompatibility rootProject.ext.sourceCompatibilityVersion
    }
}
def SUPPORT_LIB_VER = '27.1.1'
def SDP_VERSION = '1.0.5'
def BUTTER_KNIFE_VER = '8.8.1'
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}"
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${BUTTER_KNIFE_VER}"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${BUTTER_KNIFE_VER}"
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.0'
    implementation "com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:$SDP_VERSION"
    implementation "com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:$SDP_VERSION"
    implementation group: 'org.simpleframework', name: 'simple-xml', version: '2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
}
```

**Exported versions**

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
    minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    sourceCompatibilityVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibilityVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

I downgraded `build.gradle` to make this working but that's not a solution. Someone know this issue?

Comment: What's your target SDK version.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: issue occurs on gradle sync right?

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari Do i need to mention in my question that i have tried all the things that can be tried?

Comment: @JojoNarte Yes i can not build project.

Comment: @Khemraj this is happening because your cache not cleared or its unable to creating cache files again.  check gradle xml file of your build dependencies in  libraries folder under .idea folder . if you find xml file of recyclerview  old or new version then it clear that its cache problem

Comment: try to change sequence of  `allprojects {
    repositories{}` , first `jcenter()` then ` maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` and then ` maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`

Comment: in `allprojects`   `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }'` both line are identical and both are used for same purpose so remove one of them as well

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari That's true but does not make solution.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel Same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 in Android Studio new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448502/could-not-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-1-0-in-android-studio-new)

Comment: "I downgraded build.gradle to make this working but that's not a solution. Someone know this issue?" You mean if you downgrade, it's working? Which version is working?

Comment: @Khemraj - did you try annswer below

Comment: @YosiPramajaya I tried `build.gradle version 2.3.3` for make this work

Answer (score 4):

This is because You have updated all `compile` to `implementation` in your build.gradle "App level"

To solve this - Go to your **`build.gradle (Project level)`**

> and You just need to add **google() on top of jcenter() inside
>   repositories blockes.**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Take this code and put inside your build.gradle "Project Level"

Comment: I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: whats the status?

Comment: I did not mark right because i could not check it. I have given upvote for your kind efforts. I will sure try this after some time when i'll be free.

Answer (score 1):

Add `google()` to your `allprojects` >> `repositories` block. You don't need to add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` and consecutive maven block.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it works using lower version of Gradle, means that MOST PROBABLY it's not because of repository.

Maybe it's because of your `buildToolsVersion`. I didn't see you put it in your `build.gradle`. Please make sure it is 27.0.3.

Have you check in your SDK Manager? You can make sure that your SDK Manager didn't use older version of SDK Build Tools.

**SDK Tools** -> Check **Show Package Details** (on left bottom) -> Install Build Tools version 27.0.3, and uninstall older Build Tools version