# Android studio cannot resolve External libraties after updating to 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated android studio to 3.1.3 . After updating all external libraries i implemented, showing "Cannot resolve this method". But it's working fine, i can run the app. It even showing setOnClickListener in red color.

**Build.gradle(App)**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "satlaa.mysql_test"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 16
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunne
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.bogdwellers:pinchtozoom:0.1'
implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0'
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.3.0'
}
```

**Build.gradle(Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
  }

 allprojects {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
 }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried to delete gradle cache. I even did invalidate cache and restart.[image]

Comment: You can clean project or `File` -> `Invalidate Caches`

Comment: I mention it in my question that i did it.

Comment: after this [could-not-resolve-recyclerview-v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50902984/could-not-resolve-recyclerview-v7)  issue with glide, recyclerview solved. but not with volley.

Comment: Rebuild your project.

Comment: @Dennis problem solved after i remove volley implementation, then run the app and it gave error. Then again reimplemetated volley and it worked.

Comment: @Dennis we should run after removing implementation and it should gave error. Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: I had that in mind, but that's not really an actual fix, it's more of manipulating the software's state :p I guess your AndroidStudio might have encountered a bug.

Comment: @Dennis maybe. You asked for my project on github. I uploaded there.

Comment: Can I have the link please? Thanks!

Comment: @Dennis https://github.com/anjaan7664/MySQL_test

Comment: I'll get back to you in the evening ( GTM +5:30)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes this happens because of libraries cache what you can try is:

1. Do invalidate cache and restart which is in the file menu

Or you can manually do this which is really effective:

2. Go to `\YourProject\.idea\libraries` and delete all libraries containing `support` in their names and also delete `volley` library if you've added it

Now recompile the code