# React Native - Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to build my React Native project

```
react-native run-android
```

I get this error

```
Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0.
....
 Required by: project :react-native-maps
...
 Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
```

However, my `build.gradle` file has

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
```

and the builTools **28.0.3** exist in my *~/Library/Android/sdk/tools*, i have also tried using both

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+"
```

This doesn't work for me either.

- ### [Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 in Android Studio new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448502/could-not-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-1-0-in-android-studio-new)

Comment: check your `/node_modules/react-native-maps` folder. this package is using `support-compat:26.1.0`. maybe some version changes in its configuration solve your problem

Comment: I hear you, but i don't understand. Is there a specific file i should change inside `/node_modules/react-native-maps`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by upgrading to the latest version of the *react-native-maps* plugin.

`npm install --save "react-native-maps@react-native-community/react-native-maps#master"`.

I think its very important to make sure that all plugins are updated, especially if you haven't touched your project for some time and when you do everything just breaks.