# Trouble with gradle in android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I know about this questions:

[Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0 android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45103230/2263683)

[Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47035406/2263683)

[Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 in Android Studio new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448502/could-not-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-1-0-in-android-studio-new)

And I've read this documentations:

[Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

[Migrating to Android 8.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html#ptb)

*So I'm posting this question believing its not a duplicate.*

I've installed Android Studio 3.4.1. I didn't have any previous version before and I started a new project.

Every setting in Gradle file have been set by Android Studio itself and I've checked them all.

**I have already tried**

- invalidate and restart android studio
- [Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 in Android Studio new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448502/could-not-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-1-0-in-android-studio-new)
- [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android)

These are the file contents:

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

}
```

**Top level build.gradle**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://maven.google.com/'}
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/guardian/android' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
 #Mon Jun 10 17:40:01 IST 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

I use `google()` in repositories as [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html#ptb) clearly says:

> ```
>   // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
>      // maven {
>      //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
>      // }
> ```

My gradle version is 4.1 so I don't need above code.

But I still get this error as the others have been asking about:

- > Unable to resolve dependency for
  >   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
  >   androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3.
- > ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
  >   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
  >   androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0.
- > ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
  >   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
  >   androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0.
- > ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
  >   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
  >   androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0.
- > ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
  >   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
  >   androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0.
- > ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
  >   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
  >   androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0.

I have also unchecked the offline check box from gradle and using default

[image: I have also unchecked the offline check box from gradle and using default]

Why should I get this error when I'm creating a new project in `AS 3.4.1` and it has been set all the necessary settings?

Comment: Have you tried this steps if you are going to use AndroidX. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54825603/1318946

Comment: Yes I did. It says no usages found. @PratikButaniAndroidDev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to mix AppCompat and Jetpack dependencies, and you cannot do that.

I think you might not have the right repository setup for the Jetpack libraries (why it can't find any Jetpack libraries).

Don't use: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' . (this is Jetpack) -- use AppCompat versions of this (besides - Jetpack is NOT consistent with Appcompat versions earlier then 28.x). Bottom line, get rid of anything that says (androidx).

Comment: what should I do? remove @Booger

Comment: Don't use: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' . (this is Jetpack) -- use AppCompat versions of this (besides - Jetpack is NOT consistent with Appcompat versions earlier then 28.x).  Bottom line, get rid of anything that says (androidx).

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
```

**EDIT**:-
 You should invalidate your cache and restart. Follow this steps `file` -> `invalidate caches/Restart` Then select `invalidate and restart`

Comment: I did removed it but still got these errors @PrachiSingh

Comment: @user1 First uncheck 'Offline Work' in `settings`->`gradle`->`Offline Work`. Then You should invalidate your cache and restart. Follow this steps `file` -> `invalidate caches/Restart` Then select `invalidate and restart`

Comment: I have already disabled that see my question I have edited my question @PrachiSingh

Answer (score 1):

Define repositories for both Appcompat and jetpack

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()        
        maven {url 'https://maven.google.com/'}
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/guardian/android' }
    }
}
```

After that sync project with gradle.. let me know its working or not.

Comment: I did changed the gradle files but still got these errors @Hemant Parmar

Comment: are you using any lib project ?

Comment: No, Its my first android project. I just created an android project with default settings @Hemant Parmar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194707/discussion-between-user1-and-hemant-parmar).

Comment: You can't mix AppCompat and Jetpack, so this is a bad idea.  Pick one or the other.